# Get namespace of unqualified class name

Tags: php, namespaces

Consider the following PHP code

```
namespace foo\bar;

class MyClass {}

namespace xyz;
use foo\bar\MyClass;

class OtherClass {}

$a = new MyClass();
$b = new OtherClass();
```

`$a` is an instance of `\foo\bar\MyClass`, while `$b` is an instance of `\xyz\OtherClass`. These fully qualified class names, I can get by calling `get_class($a)` and `get_class($b)`. But is there a way to get the fully qualified names without instantiating the objects? Is there something like a magic function `fully_qualified_class_name` such that `fully_qualified_class_name('MyClass')` would return `\foo\bar\MyClass`, and `fully_qualified_class_name('OtherClass')` would return `\xyz\OtherClass`? Or do I just have to write the fully qualified name myself?

Comment: and what `fully_qualified_class_name('MyClass')` should return if exist a `\foo\bar\MyClass` class and a `\foo\anotherbar\MyClass` class?

Comment: This would never happen, as `use foo\bar\MyClass; use foo\anotherbar\MyClass;` would cause a fatal "name is already in use"-error.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From php 5.5 you can use the class name resolution via `::class`

```
namespace foo\bar {
    class MyClass {}
}

namespace xyz {
    use foo\bar\MyClass;

    class OtherClass {}

    echo 'OtherClass namespace: ', OtherClass::class, "\n"; // print "OtherClass namespace: xyz\OtherClass"
    echo 'MyClass namespace: ', MyClass::class, "\n"; // print "MyClass namespace: foo\bar\MyClass"
}
```